export jar file from eclipse not working in macOS
I have tried to export a jar file to macOS desktop its exported by eclipse. I can run the program in eclipse how I want it. But I click on the jar file it does nothing except give me this error.

I try to launch it from terminal. I get this error:
Error: Could not find or load main class Main
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application
johnzalubski@Johns-MacBook-Pro desktop %.

I don't know if I need to do something with maven. I have added java jfx from the eclipse marketplace.

The example outlined here can be run in any of several ways shown here. Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] that shows your current approach.

Eclipse Run Configurations window has a Show Command button. Click on it and Eclipse will display the command it uses to run your application. Compare that with how you are trying to run the JAR, i.e. file Majority.jar. Also check the MANIFEST.MF file in the JAR. Does it have a Class-Path header? What JDK are you using? Is it OpenJDK? Does it include JavaFX or not? Zulu is a JDK that includes JavaFX.

@arba I did a run from configurations and got this error java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at

Quick fix: Download this project and alter it to your needs: https://github.com/davidweber411/javafx-JavaFxAppMavenNonModular This should work out of the box.
